# With EL, is it possible to do field access on beans rather than getters/setters?

Tags: jsf, el, getter-setter, field-accessors

## EDIT

Take this answer with a grain of salt. Much has changed since I asked this question years ago. I recommend now using Lombok instead of my EL solution. Leaving the original question for historical reasons.

---

I'm serious tired of getters/setters clogging my code, when I don't need to control access to the internal state of an object. The only real reason I have to still generate getters/setters is because EL works by locating methods, not fields: `${myBean.fieldName}`. where `fieldName` refers to the method `getFieldName()`. Would it be possible to extend an EL Resolver to just return the public field value unless a getter was found?

---

Update based on answer of Steve Atkinson:
I hope this helps someone else. Notice how I explicitly check that I only use this elresolver on Form or Lead objects, which are my domain objects.

```
public class PublicFieldSupportingELResolver extends ELResolver {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getCommonPropertyType(ELContext context, Object base) {
        if (base instanceof Form || base instanceof Lead) {
            try {
                context.setPropertyResolved(true);
                return base.getClass();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                context.setPropertyResolved(false);
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            context.setPropertyResolved(false);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<FeatureDescriptor> getFeatureDescriptors(ELContext context, Object base) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getType(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        if (base instanceof Form || base instanceof Lead) {
            try {
                Field field = base.getClass().getField((String) property);
                context.setPropertyResolved(true);
                return field.getType();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                context.setPropertyResolved(false);
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            context.setPropertyResolved(false);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        if (base instanceof Form || base instanceof Lead) {
            try {
                Field field = base.getClass().getField((String) property);
                Object value = field.get(base);
                context.setPropertyResolved(true);
                return value;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                context.setPropertyResolved(false);
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            context.setPropertyResolved(false);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadOnly(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {
        if (base instanceof Form || base instanceof Lead) {
            try {
                base.getClass().getField((String) property);
                context.setPropertyResolved(true);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                context.setPropertyResolved(false);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            context.setPropertyResolved(false);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property, Object value) {
        if (base instanceof Form || base instanceof Lead) {
            try {
                Field field = base.getClass().getField((String) property);
                field.set(base, value);
                context.setPropertyResolved(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                context.setPropertyResolved(false);
            }
        } else {
            context.setPropertyResolved(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: this won't necessarily work for proxied beans (e.g. CDI).

Comment: Yeah, this really shouldn't be done anymore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`@Getter`/`@Setter`](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html) annotations from [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html) if you don't want to write/generate getter and setter method(s) on your Java Bean.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Jsf is very extensible, pretty much everything can be extended or replaced.

A great example of custom resolvers is [here](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2005/12/28/how_to_write_your_own/)

The guy was using it to populate dropdown lists from database queries. I'm certain you could use similar techniques to resolve based on public fields rather than public get/set methods.

Comment: If I replace the el-resolver element in my faces-config, I can't use the default one. Any way to just tack an additional resolver on without replacing the default one?

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher yeah well an answer to that would have been much appreciated

Comment: See the Edit on the first post :)