# Using public field, will it mess with the proxies?

Tags: jsf, cdi

I'm wondering if changing the EL resolver so a bean can use public fields in jsf could cause issues with the proxies? [That's why it isn't a duplicate.] Aall managed bean fields have to be private in the framework, because that's how the EL resolver does things. However it's a bit cumbersome and looks useless most of the time.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class myBean{
    public int age;
}
```

So would it cause issue with proxies trying to intercept things or whatnot?

This guy in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610522/with-java-el-2-2-jsf2-is-it-possible-to-do-field-access-rather-than-getters-se) apparently changed the el resolver so it's doable

Comment: please do not refer to other questions. try to make your question as atomic as possible (the other question can be removed)

Comment: @Leo allright I'll edit that

Comment: So, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Java EL 2.2 / JSF2 Is it possible to do field access rather than getters/setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610522/with-java-el-2-2-jsf2-is-it-possible-to-do-field-access-rather-than-getters-se)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Read again, this isn't a duplicate of that. I even linked it in the question. And I posted my question after reading that exact link. My question is about proxies potentially interfering with the process. I have suspicions that the link (indirectly the answer) you & I linked is wrong ence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately yes, it will mess with CDI.

Why? Because public field access is impossible when bean is proxied. With `Weld` during startup you will get a definition error:

```
WELD-000075: Normal scoped managed bean implementation class has a public field ...
```

It's going to work fine only for non-proxied scopes (`@Singleton` and `@Dependant`).

I agree it's a bit cumbersome and looks useless sometimes, so you have two solutions:

1. Use IDE to generate them automatically.
2. Use [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) project.

But none of them is perfect.

Comment: You are on a roll ! Thanks